# Given a set of positive numbers, find the additive combinations that are the closest possible to a given constant?

Tags: python, math, set, combinations, combinatorics

Let's say I have a set of numbers.Now I want to find out by what additive combinations will they deviate from 0.2 the least(in total)? Each number can only pair with **one** other number.

For example, the numbers are 0.1, 0.15, 0.3, 0.2, and 0.13... Pair_1: 0.1+0.15, pair_2= 0.3+02... then let *d_i* be the deviation of pair i, how to find the additive combinations that achieve the minimal sum of d_i?

I have done a lot of thinking and searching, still could not solve this question by Python.
One combination that deviate from 0.2 the least could cause another combination to deviate from it more.

SOS plz

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This sounds like homework. Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I wrote to solve the problem based on my understanding of the question:

```
list_of_numbers = [0.1, 0.15, 0.3, 0.2, 0.13]
base_number = 0.2

def devianceFrom(number, list_of_numbers):
    results = []
    combinations = []
    for i in range(0, len(list_of_numbers)):
        for j in range(0, len(list_of_numbers)):
            if j > i or j == i:
                continue
            else:
                results.append(list_of_numbers[j] + list_of_numbers[i])
                combinations.append([list_of_numbers[j], list_of_numbers[i]])
    for n in range(0, len(results)):
        results[n] = abs(results[n]-number)
    minCombo = min(results)
    index = results.index(minCombo)
    try:
        for ind in index:
            print("{} is the minimum difference using the sum of {} and {}.".format(results[ind], combinations[ind][0], combinations[ind][1]))
    except:
        print("{} is the minimum difference using the sum of {} and {}.".format(results[index], combinations[index][0], combinations[index][1]))

devianceFrom(base_number, list_of_numbers)
```

However, this will only find one set that is the minimum. So, if you need ALL combos that create the minimum difference then it will need some modifications.

edit:
The print that it gives is "0.03 is the minimum difference using the sum of 0.1 and 0.13."

If this is not the answer you are looking for please explain further. Also, I can send commented code or an explanation of the code if needed.

Comment: I astonished and amazed..! This is the first time I use SO and I dd not expect to get an answer, at least not this first and elaborated. Thank you so so much!

Comment: And as to the question, I am sorry that I did not make it clear that I want to find ALL combos that create the minimum difference, for example, numbers are a, b, c and d, constant(or base_number) is C, the combos are a+d and b+c such that |(a+d)-C)| + |(b+c)-C| <= |(a+b)-C)|+|(c+d)-C|. How to get all the combos is the hardest part because I suppose finding the best combo each time is not equal to finding the system/overall best combos.

Comment: (1) use the code and find the first combo (2)eliminate the first combo (3) run the code again would be a way to solve the question, but I guess it will not solve for the BEST combos? Since each run of the code, it only considers one combo and neglects the rest, making the later combos together contributing to a greater d_i.

Comment: sorry I want to cast a up vote, but it says that I do not have enough reputation.

Comment: @fleong you can accept it though.